# Building ssldump on Ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl, tcpdump, f5

Has anyone built ssldump on Ubuntu lately?   I am having trouble building http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ssldump/ssldump/0.9b3/ssldump-0.9b3.tar.gz - it appears to be referencing libraries that are too old for Ubuntu 12.04.  I am trying this so that I can apply the TLS patch that is at http://sourceforge.net/p/ssldump/patches/8/.

If anyone has specific instructions to build ssldump, please share.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the necessary development libraries (personally, the easiest way for me is to "`sudo apt-get install gnome-devel`")

- `sudo apt-get install libpcap0.8-dev`
- `sudo ln -sf /usr/include/pcap-bpf.h /usr/include/net/bpf.h`
- `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`
- Then cd into the ssldump source directory and: `./configure --host=i686-pc-linux-gnu --with-pcap-lib=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`

  - `make -j4`

That should get you there. It worked for me on ubuntu 15.04. I may have missed out a few things though, cos I did it a couple of weeks ago, so if something doesn't work, leave a comment.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to build it too, but when I run ssldump exits with the error 'ERROR: Length mismatch'.  I tried capturing the traffic with tcpdump using '-s 0' and feeding the dump to ssldump but I get the same error.  Are you able to successfully run the ssldump that you built? Thanks.